# Dead keys not working in Remmina, RDP connection

Tags: keyboard, rdp

Even with "Grab all keys" option checked, dead keys don't work properly. They are simply ignored, other than with a following space bar, which generates only the corresponding diacritic: ['] + [ ] generates ['], ['] + [e] generates [e], and so on.

Is there some other configuration parameter that may affect the keyboard behavior I should consider?

Remmina 1.4.5 on Uqbuntu 20.04; connection with Windows 8.1

Possibly related question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57725/remmina-doesnt-eat-keys

Comment: I don't know how to better formulate it as a question; I hope it is now adequate. I lost a lot of time trying to fix this problem, and just simply thought what I found might be helpful for someone else.

Comment: (The explicit question added makes the difference between a problem complaint and an answerable question - in my eyes. Alas, while using RDP regularly in the office (armbian↔MS W2K)(*U**q**buntu*?), I'm ignorant of *Remmina*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the 'Use the client keyboard layout' general option (RDP section) also matters; when checked, dead keys don't work properly (as described), even if both keyboard layouts are the same (US International).

Unchecking it resolves the problem.